# Problem in BibTeX with composite names

Tags: bibtex

In my .bib file, I have this entry:

```
@conference{HCS96,
  title={The Virtual Cinematographer: A Paradigm for Automatic Real-time Camera Control and Directing},
  author={Li-wei He and Michael F. Cohen and Davih H. Salesin},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 23rd Annual Conference on Computer Graphics and Interactive Techniques},
  pages={217--224},
  isbn={0897917464},
  year={1996},
  organization={ACM}
}
```

When I compile my thesis, I get this entry in the bibliography:

```
[wei He et al., 1996] wei He, L., Cohen, M. F., and Salesin, D. H. (1996). The virtual cinematographer: A paradigm for automatic real-time camera control and directing. In Proceedings of the 23rd Annual Conference on Computer Graphics and Interactive Techniques, pages 217–224. ACM.
```

Why is the name of the first author produced this way?! It should rather be "He et al., 1996". Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: My general advice for many problems with bibliographies: *don't* use `bibtex`, use `amsrefs` or `biblatex` instead.

Comment: How are amsrefs adn biblatex better than bibtex?

Comment: Just a few points:

1. They are both easier to customize (formatting through LaTeX and not .bst files).

2. `amsrefs` is written entirely in LaTeX, you don't need external programs, just another LaTeX pass.

3. Input syntax is much cleaner in `amsrefs` (no "and" as a seperator, for example, repeated fields).

4. Multiple bibliographies are very easy in `amsrefs`.

5. `biblatex` allows for non-English bibliographies (utf-8, sorting).

6. `biblatex` allows for "ibid." style of citations.

(Disclaimer: I've never used `biblatex`, I've only skimmed through its documentation.)

Comment: @mbork: while it's true -- as a general proposition -- that `amsrefs` and `biblatex` are more versatile *and* easier to customize than plain ole `bibtex`, I fail to see the relevance of this observation in the present case (formatting of a name where the given name is hyphenated along with a nonstandard capitalization of part of the given name).

Comment: I do not know bibtex very well - I haven't used it for quite a long time - but you are probably right.  My point - as I stated it - was general.  It is kind of a script of mine: whenever someone says "I have a problem with bibtex", I tend to answer "Then don't use it", since the person might as well run into more serious problems (or questions), when switching to amsrefs/biblatex might actually help.

Comment: So while technically my remark might be irrelevant, it is nonetheless a good idea to have a pointer to amsrefs/biblatex in most questions of the "I have a problem with bibtex" type, so that people will gradually switch to these better tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually, issues with a name in BibTeX can be resolved by enclosing the mistreated part in `{}`, so if you write your author line like this:

```
  author={{Li-wei} He and Michael F. Cohen and Davih H. Salesin},
```

you will be fine. I just tested it on a dummy file with this one fix to your entry, and -- using `apalike` for my style -- I got this result:

---

**References**

[He et al., 1996] He, L., Cohen, M. F., and Salesin, D. H. (1996). The virtual cinematographer: A paradigm for automatic real-time camera control and directing. In *Proceedings of the 23rd Annual Conference on Computer Graphics and Interactive Techniques*, pages 217–224. ACM.

Comment: This just took me out of trouble. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

Another (tested) solution would be to switch to lastname, firstnames

```
 author={He, Li-wei and Cohen, Michael F. and Salesin, Davih H.},
```

This form is generally preferrable whenever you have three names, double-last-names etc.